# Hide SuiteBar links Office 365

Tags: 2013, jquery, master-page, suite-links, suitebar

I have previously used jQuery to hide the Suitebar links in SP 2013. This was on-prem install. When I try in Office 365, it seems to ignore the code.

//Neither of these work:

```
$("span:contains('OneDrive')").css('display', 'none');

document.getElementById("suiteLinksBox").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Also, I tried doing this through the Admin center but it doesn't hide anything. Why not?

http://joshuakirchmeier.com/2014/06/02/hiding-suite-bar-links-sharepoint-online-office-365/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* Hide  SuiteBar OneDrive */
a#Suite_MainLink_ShellDocuments {
    display: none !important;
}

/* To hide entire suiteBar */
div#suiteBarTop {
   display: none;
}
```

You can also use Admin settings to show/hide few of the suite bar links.

Comment: I have tried the Admin settings and it doesn't do anything. But your css does, TY!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('suiteBarTop').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: thx, but that didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

How to hide SuiteBar links in Office365

Using jQuery:

```
$('.o365cs-nav-O365Links').hide();
```

Using Css:

```
.o365cs-nav-O365LinksContainer .o365cs-nav-O365Links {
   display: none;
}
```